# How can i edit videos in compositing mode?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, edit-mode, video, keyframes

ok so i understand how to edit videos in the movie/video editor that blender has but i would much rather edit my videos in compositing mode via using a movie clip and simply applying all of the various node types to it rather than the setup of the movie editor. [image: my setup] and i am able to edit movies through this but the main question is: is it possible for me to edit videos this way and preview them like transfer the compositor edited clip to the movie editor without rendering it out with no real idea how it looks.
things to note: 
I am using Cycles as shown in the image
I am only using one video nothing else
The main reason i like compositing is it has more versatility than the video editor.

Comment: There is no preview buffer for the compositor, . You'll never b e able to view any kind of real time preview. Editing would then be a very slow and painful process of rendering out every single change. My advise is to use a dedicated and mature video editing app, there are a number of them out there.

Comment: yes cegaton i know i should but i am not paying monthly for an editing software or converting to lenox just to edit. i can edit with it but there has to be some way to preview.

Comment: also, there has to be some way to use nodes in correlation to the Video Editor

Comment: you can use resolve, its free version is a very powerful video editor.

Comment: Think of the VSE and the Compostior as a disfunctional marriage: They coexist but don't communicate...

Comment: well, cegation. this did not solve my problem because almost anything i want to do in the Free version of Resolve pops up with a watermark AND A HUGE watermark that urges me to buy the studio version which is $995 bringing me back to my original issue of having to pay for a worthy editing software

Comment: Try [Natron](https://natron.fr/), node based, free, and does have cached preview.

Comment: What kind of compositing effects are you trying to do?

Comment: videos like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ze8lmCOw2Vw so a lot of distortion and color change, granted Resolve And Blender are very easy for the color factor but the distortions are a pain (would be easy in Resolve if it wasn't 1 grand)